PostgreSQL 16: SELECT returns rows but UPDATE with the same WHERE clause finds none
I am encountering an issue in PostgreSQL 16 where a SELECT query returns 4 rows, but using the same WHERE clause in an UPDATE statement results in no rows being found.
I examined the query plans and noticed a difference in the join operations. The UPDATE statement uses a Merge Right Anti Join with actual rows=0, while the SELECT query uses a Merge Anti Join with actual rows=4.
Here are the query plans for both the UPDATE and SELECT statements:
Update Query Plan:
Update on financial f (actual rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Right Anti Join (actual rows=0 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (cm.invoice_card_id = f.financial_id)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_moviment_account_invoice_card_id on moviment_account cm (actual rows=244 loops=1)
        ->  Sort (actual rows=40 loops=1)
              Sort Key: f.financial_id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
              ->  Index Scan using idx_financial_sale_of on financial f (actual rows=40 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (sale_of IS NULL)
                    Filter: ((canceled = '0'::bpchar) AND (kind = 'credit_card'::financial_kind))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1644
Planning Time: 0.219 ms
Execution Time: 0.574 ms

Select Query Plan:
Aggregate (actual rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Anti Join (actual rows=4 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (f.financial_id = cm.invoice_card_id)
        ->  Sort (actual rows=40 loops=1)
              Sort Key: f.financial_id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Index Scan using idx_financial_sale_of on financial f (actual rows=40 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (sale_of IS NULL)
                    Filter: ((canceled = '0'::bpchar) AND (kind = 'credit_card'::financial_kind))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1644
        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_moviment_account_invoice_card_id on moviment_account cm (actual rows=242 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.205 ms
Execution Time: 0.468 ms

The key differences I observed are:
Update Plan: Uses Merge Right Anti Join with actual rows=0
Select Plan: Uses Merge Anti Join with actual rows=4
What could be causing the UPDATE statement to not find any rows, while the SELECT query with the same conditions returns 4 rows? How can I modify the UPDATE query to ensure it finds and updates the correct rows?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
This query was working correctly in PostgreSQL 15, but after upgrading to version 16, it stopped working. Some of the things I tried that worked include:

Changing the NOT EXISTS clause to (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM moviment_account MA WHERE MA.invoice_card_id = F.FINANCIAL_ID) = 0
Removing the index idx_moviment_account_invoice_card_id also allowed the records to be updated.
However, I am not satisfied with these solutions and would like to understand why this issue is occurring.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
